# How to get involved in a conversation happening on the seats across from you on a coach

Tags: conversations, public-transportation, friends

Often on a trip, there will be an odd number of people from my school getting involved. As a result, one person will be left isolated on their own pair of chairs (chairs on coaches are pairs of 2 chairs, one on the left and one on the right) and often I'm left alone on a pair of chairs by myself. Across from me on the pair of chairs next to me are some friends that are happily engaging in conversation, as they are not sat next to me (there is an aisle running down the coach between us) they aren't really including me in the conversation.

I don't want to directly ask or point out that I'm not being included, as they're not deliberately leaving me out. So is there any way to easily engage with them across the aisle to make conversation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're too far from there, you might wanna get a seat nearby to them. If there is a relatively long distance between your seats, you will have to raise your voice and talking in high voice might damage your vocal chords. Also, it might imply that you really wanna join this conversation.

If you're near to their seats, then it's good. **Now you just have to pick a conversation subject which you can contribute to.**

In this way, you can start a conversation without showing any eagerness to join it.